# Returning empty data from database in angular js

Tags: angularjs-service

I am using angular js http.get method to fetch data from database with php script, but having problem when php returns empty record. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Put records in your database ? More seriously, please post some code so that we can help you, and also some data from your database if you can. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

A minimalist answer for a minimalist question

```
if(yourObjectFromDatabase != null) {...}
```